# Page doesn't load when I set variable to 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, var

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    var attempts = 0 
    var maximum = 3
    
    while (attempts < maximum){
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() { 
            attempts += 1;
                if (document.getElementById("input").value == randomNumber) {
                    alert("You chose the right number");
                } else {
                    alert("WRONG Number! You have " + attempts + " attempts.");
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
 <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

while learning how to use a random number generator, I wantd to add a while loop and give 3 attempts to choose from a random number. 
When I create a variable to set the number of attempts, if I make the variable equal to 0, my page doesn't load, but if I leave the variable empty without a value, the script doesn't run.

Any ideas of why this may be happening?

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    var x = 0
    var maximum = 3
    
    while (x < maximum){
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() { 
            attempts += 1;
                if (document.getElementById("input").value == randomNumber) {
                    alert("You chose the right number");
                } else {
                    alert("WRONG Number! You have " + attempts + " attempts.");
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The page isn't loading because while(x < maximum) is an infinite loop since 0 < 3 always.

Comment: You never change `x` (or `maximum`) inside the loop, so the loop never ends.

Comment: Ps. To avoid having to ask on SO about trivial little bugs like this in the future, please consider learning [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It's easy to become blind to bugs in your own code if you've been looking at it too long, but you'd probably have easily caught this one if you'd [explained to a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) line by line what your code does. Or stepped through it in your browser's JS debugger.

Comment: Im sorry, I was doing some changes to the code before I posted it here. The variable name is attempts. On the second line of the While Loop im adding `attempts += 1` to increase the number. (Check updated post)
But still even if attempts number never increased and the variable always stayed in 0, I don't think it should be an error or infinity loop, it just makes the loop always True allowing to always work.

Comment: It's still an infinite loop. Why not try the rubber duck method and see if you can figure out yourself why? (Hint: Where is the line `attempts += 1` located? When does it get executed?)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, I don't know how to use JS Debugger, I'm learning to code, I have been doing this for about 3 weeks only. My goal is to learn all those tools, but so far I'm not there yet.

Comment: Your should learn soon. It's not hard, and will make programming a lot easier. You can find lots of tutorials online; here's one: https://javascript.info/debugging-chrome

Comment: (Honestly, saying "I'm not using a debugger yet, I've just started learning how to program" is kind of like saying "I'm not using the handlebars yet, I've just started learning how to ride a bike." You're just making things harder for yourself for no good reason.)

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I will take a look at it!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop runs synchronously, during pageload. The script never finishes, because the `while` loop's condition is never negated, so control is never yielded back to the browser to repaint the page, so the user never has a chance to input a number or click on the button.

While you could keep using `while` by promisifying the onclick and `await`ing a Promise, it'd be better to create the handler outside, once, and have *it* check if the attempts are maxed out.

You also need to use consistent variable names: either use `x` or `attempts`, not both:

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var attempts = 0
var maximum = 3

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
  if (attempts >= maximum) return;
  attempts += 1;
  if (document.getElementById("input").value == randomNumber) {
    alert("You chose the right number");
  } else {
    alert("WRONG Number! You have " + attempts + " attempts.");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button after the maximum number of attempts has been reached, like:

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var attempts = 0;
var maximum = 3;

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(e) {
  attempts += 1;
  if (document.getElementById("input").value == randomNumber) {
    alert("You chose the right number");
  } else {
    alert("WRONG Number! You have " + attempts + " attempts.");
  }
  if (attempts === maximum) e.target.disabled = true;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```